# Round number to decimal places

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a javascript in html body for a BMI Calculator. Everything is working so far on my own accord. I just need help with two things which i cant just figure out.
Firstly i cant get the output BMI calculation to 2 decimal places. I have tried using toFixed(2) and double with no luck.

And also When you input the first variables it highlights the comments in the table. When you do a second input (with different outcome) it highlights a new field and keeps the old one. (not refreshing itself) and also cannot figure that.

Script below

```
        <html>

      <head>

    <title>Body Mass Index (BMI) Calculator</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    //Variables Input

    <!--
        function calcBmi() {
var weight = document.bmiForm.weight.value //Input of Weight

var height = document.bmiForm.height.value //Input of Height



//Calculation of BMI

if(weight > 0 && height > 0){   
var finalbmi = weight/(height/100*height/100)
document.bmiForm.finalbmi.value = finalbmi

//Incorrect Input of Numeric Variables
var rvalue = true
if ( (weight < 30) || (weight > 450) ) 
    {   alert ("Invalid weight. Please check and re-enter");
        rvalue = false
    }
if ( (height < 80) || (height > 300) ) 
        {   alert ("Invalid Height. Please check and re-enter");
        rvalue = false
    }
//Highlighted Decisions are made below

if(finalbmi < 18){
document.getElementById('tr1').style.backgroundColor="grey";
    }
    if(finalbmi > 18 && finalbmi < 19.999){
    document.getElementById('tr2').style.backgroundColor="grey";
}
if(finalbmi > 20 && finalbmi < 25.999){
document.getElementById('tr3').style.backgroundColor="grey";
}
if(finalbmi > 26 && finalbmi < 30.999){
document.getElementById('tr4').style.backgroundColor="grey";
}
if(finalbmi > 31){
document.getElementById('tr5').style.backgroundColor="grey";
}
}
//Incorrect Characters Inserted, this message is an error code
else{
alert("Error, Please Fill In Numeric values Only ") 
}
}
//-->
//--> CSS Style Formatting
</script>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 100%;
            }
        .wrapper {
            margin: 0 auto; 
            width: 800px;
            }
        table {
            width: 500px;
            border: 10px solid #666;
            margin: 0 auto;
            }
        form {
            text-align: center;
            }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form name="bmiForm">
            <p>
            <p>
            Your Weight(kg): <input type="text" name="weight" size="11"><br />
            <p>
            <p>
            Your Height(cm): <input type="text" name="height" size="11"><br />
            <p>
            <p>
            <input type="button" value="Calculate BMI" onClick="calcBmi()"><br />

            <p>
            <p>
            Your BMI: <input type="text" name="finalbmi" size="11"><br />
            <p>
            <p>
            <!--Highlighted Desicions shown below -->
            <table id="bmitable" border="1" width="40%" cellpadding="5"     cellspacing="5" style="background-color:white;">
            <tr id='tr1'>
                     <td colspan="2"><font size="2">Under 18 - Your Are     Very Underweight and Possibly Malnourished.</font></td>
            </tr>
        <tr id='tr2'>
                     <td colspan="2"><font size="2">Under 20 - You Are     Underweight and Could Afford to Gain a Little Weight.</font></td>
        </tr>
            <tr id='tr3'>
                     <td colspan="2"><font size="2">20 to 25 - You Have a     Healthy Weight Range for a Young and Middle-Aged Adults.</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='tr4'>
                     <td colspan="2"><font size="2">26 to 30 - You Are     Overweight.<font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='tr5'>
                     <td colspan="2"><font size="2">Over 30 - You Are     Obese</font></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>  
<div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do not bet here  and java is not javascript.

Comment: fair enough, but why not here, i have seen similar question asked and answered in regards to the decimal issue. I have tried to do the research before hand to even comming this far.

Comment: I may not solve your problem. But the reason for getting downvotes and  no answers is you are not demonstrated your problem briefly. you just dumped your code and asked for help. Please cut down your code and post the suspected code. If possible create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). People love to solve  well understood question :) hope you understand.

Comment: For future reference, your title is awful. It should tell us something about your problem. Perhaps something like "round number to two decimal places" would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toFixed worked for me

```
document.bmiForm.finalbmi.value = new Number(finalbmi).toFixed(2);
```

Also you need to set background of other trs to white as below

```
if(finalbmi < 18){
     document.getElementById('tr1').style.backgroundColor="grey";
}
else{
     document.getElementById('tr1').style.backgroundColor="white";
}
```

[Click Here for Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zDc47/)

Comment: thanks, i see what you ment, i was adding

    document.bmiForm.finalbmi.value = finalbmi.toFixed(2);